# Overlay one image with another without extending parent height

Tags: html, css

I had a front image on the page, inserted like this:

```
<h1>
    <a href...>
        <img .../>
    </a>
</h1>
```

Now I want to add another image link, to overlay first one (it is smaller image so it would be Ok):

```
<h1>
    <a href...>
        <img .../>
    </a>
    <a href... style="position:relative;top:-150px;">
        <img ... style="height:150px"/>
    </a>
</h1>
```

It does what I want, but the height of the parent `H1` is still enlarged by these `150px` leaving silly empty space.

I made height of `H1` predefined constant to solve this, however I'm interested in more proper / elegant solution.

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Use `position:relative` on the `h1`, and `position:absolute` on the second link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I need to mention if you are using inline styles remove it and add an external style sheet.

Below I am giving the answer with inline styles just because you have used them too in your question .Try the following:

```
<h1 style="position:relative;">
    <a href...>
        <img .../>
    </a>
    <a href... style="position:absolute;top:0;">
        <img ... style="height:150px"/>
    </a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used inline styles just to simplify the example. Thanks for you helped me to understand "relative" better!